# `#:~:text=` - выделение текста на странице с помощью гиперссылки

Tags: html, url, браузер

### Предисловие:

Браузер на базе хромиума.

### Запрос в гугле:

`https://www.google.com/?q=meme+этимология`

### Первая ссылка:

`https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Интернет-мем#:~:text=Термин%20«мем»%20впервые%20употребил%20оксфордский,в%201976%20году%2C%20ставшей%20классикой.&text=Причём%2C%20сам%20Докинз%20образовал%20термин,«мим»%20практически%20не%20используется.`

- хмм, любопытно, `#:~:text=<TEXT>` для всех браузеров генерируется?

#### #:~:text=

Если перейти по ссылке выше, то текст после `:~:text=` будет подсвечен желтым.

### Вопрос:

- Это веб стандарт? (как называется, ссылку на доки)
- Это только для браузеров на базе хромиума? Или другие тоже поддерживают/будут?

### PS

- видел кто плагин (браузер) для создания ссылок на выделенный фрагмент, поделитесь в комментариях.

там чо-т пишут про это:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162093/4794368
- а ещё там интересная ссылка на https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment#Examples (чуть ниже - Proposals)

Comment: text fragments, text url fragments - они называют это

Comment: См. также [WICG proposal](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment).

Answer (score 2):

Нашел публикацию где написано, что эта функция которая реализуется на стороне поискового движка гугла, и должна поддерживаться веб-браузером для отображения https://9to5google.com/2020/06/03/google-search-highlight-website-content/ . Из данной статьи следует, что на данный момент это не веб-стандарт. В Mozilla Firefox данный функционал не работает, т.к. она работает на движке собственной разработки отличном от Chrome

Цитата (перевод):

> После тестирования в августе прошлого года Google недавно развернул новую функцию для поиска Google.

> С помощью этой функции Google будет выделять контент из избранного фрагмента прямо на веб-странице.

> На странице поддержки Google подробно говорится, что владельцам веб-сайтов не нужно вносить какие-либо изменения для использования этой функции, это полностью автоматически. Кроме того, если Google не может «уверенно» выделить правильный контент или браузер не поддерживает эту функцию, Google просто откроет страницу как обычно.